# How to determine Principle type for data json in terraform

Tags: terraform, datasource, terraform-provider-aws

I'm learning terraform and want to know how to determine the type and identifier for principals in data json. The inline policy that I want to convert to data json is

```
"Principal" : {
            "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com",
            "AWS": [
              "${local.eks_op_role_arn}",
              "${local.eks_ng_role_arn}"
              ]
        }
```

From what I've gathered from the documentation, it might be either of these

```
 principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["s3.amazonaws.com"]
    }
```

OR

```
principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [
        "${local.eks_op_role_arn}",
        "${local.eks_ng_role_arn}"
      ]
    }
```

How do we tell that

1- it is from AWS

2- type is S3

3- define "${local.eks_op_role_arn}", "${local.eks_ng_role_arn}" ie the ARN

pls help in understanding how this works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As general note, this might help further down to see the available options. AWS is defining them and in terraform you can apply/use them. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html

To probably not overload you with details, as a general rule of thumb:

- Type: Service, is being used when an AWS Service shall be granted/denied access. The service principal is defined by the service. You can find the service principal for some services by opening AWS services that work with IAM
- Type: AWS, when an AWS IAM role or whole AWS-Account (by using its ID) , shall be granted/denied access to a resource in it's resource-based policy or in condition keys that support principals.

Assuming e.g. you want to allow your custom EKS role to be able to access your S3 bucket, and you are trying to write the S3 bucket policy for that in terraform. The bucket policy would look like that:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "example" {
  bucket = "my-tf-test-bucket"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "example_bucket_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.example.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.example_data_bucket_policy.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "example_data_bucket_policy" {

  statement {
    sid     = "ReadEKSRoles"
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["s3:GetObject", "s3:GetObjectVersion", "s3:ListBucket"]
    principals {
      identifiers = [
        local.local.eks_op_role_arn,
        local.eks_ng_role_arn]
      type        = "AWS"
    }
    resources = [
      aws_s3_bucket.example.arn,
      "${aws_s3_bucket.example.arn}/*",
    ]
  }
}
```